# Cocos2d: is it better to have single layer and add nodes or is it better to have multiple layers?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've got this little game of mine and it consists of main game screen and of quite a few "windows" which appear on the screen on top of the main screen.
In most cases it's just one window [which is over 90% of the screen], sometimes window will open up another one.
Right now, my main screen is a layer and each window I have is a CCNode I add and remove from the layer.
I am not really using any touch detection on my nodes. If I want something touchable it will be a CCMenu.
I do have plenty of CCSprites added, if that has anything to do.
I'm wondering if it's a good [performance wise] way to go? Or in other words, if there's a rationale behind changing what I have to let say have each window as a layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, two most important benefits of using multiple layers instead of single layer are touch detection and z-ordering:

1. **Touch detection**: Using multiple layers makes it easier to employ touch detection logic that makes use of the layer hierarchy since cocos2d engine passes any touch event to the layers one after another based on the hierarchy.
2. **z-ordering**: For scenarios where certain sprites are always in front of other sprites, using multiple layer makes it much easier to enforce the z-ordering rather than having to tinker with zOrder parameter when using single layer.

IMO there is not much difference performance wise between using single layer and multiple layers, **but** if you have plenty sprites on the screen at one time, and especially if there are lots of repeating sprites, I would highly recommend using `CCSpriteBatchNode` (previously known as Texture Atlas or CCSpriteSheet) which is the [recommended cocos2d method](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3abest_practices#texture_atlas) of improving game performance when dealing with big number of sprites, so I'd say single layer with sprite batch nodes is better in term of performance then multiple layers with individual sprites added directly to the layers.